# Achieve a very tricky design in html/css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    |       |
    | image |      Series of Logos
    |   &   |
    | text  |--------------------------------
    |-------|       |       |       |       |
    |       | Links | Links | Links | Links |
    | icons |       |       |       |       |
    |       |       |       |       |       |
```

I'm using bootstrap and trying to figure out a way to do this in html/css.

The tricky part is the "Series of Logos" area. Could someone give a sample code or let me know how to go about this?

Comment: Hi. Please [include an example of your current code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I'm using bootstrap css and hence the code can't be pasted here without copying everything! Let me try without the bootstrap for this particular design and get back then.

Comment: Just use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0ntzy5ud/.  You can also use http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: It's pretty simple to create a minimal example of a bootstrap page. For example: https://github.com/abhinayrathore/Bootstrap-Boilerplate/blob/master/index.htm

Comment: have you tried the img tag?

Comment: What's tricky about that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that layout similar the following in the html, although it depends on how you want your series of logos to display. To keep it easy you may need to make sure the logos are a fixed size so that you don't get some weird wrapping.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">           
                <div class="logo col-xs-12">
                    <img src="images/image.png" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, eos earum enim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="This is an icon"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="This is an icon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="This is an logo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><a href="#">link</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then use the following css to keep the images within their columns.

```
<style>
    img {max-width:100%; height:auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank You. I did on the similar line with a lot of negative padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether you asked like this but it will give some idea:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pr8xvfhe/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fullPage">
<div id="sideBar">
    <div id="imgSideBar"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
        <p>This is side bar</p></div>
        <div id="iconSideBar"><span>This space for icons</span></div>
</div>
    <div id="mainPage"></div>
    <div id="link1">
    <div class="link">link 1</div>
    <div class="link">link 2</div>
    <div class="link">link 3</div>
        <div class="link">link 4</div></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{margin:0px;

  }
#fullPage{
    width:1368px;

    height:700px;
}
#sideBar{
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
}
#imgSideBar{height:200px;}
#iconSideBar{border-top:2px solid red;}
#mainPage{margin-top: -400px;
margin-left: 101px;width:400px;height:180px;border:1px solid red;}
.link{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
height: 180px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 121px;
display: table-cell;
}
#link1{margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: 35px;}
```

Comment: Thank You so much :)

I've got it. Wish i could upvote you but couldn't since i have little reputation to do so :(